# Reliable way to get Device Phone Number

Tags: javascript, cordova

I cant seem to find a reliable method of getting device phone number using Cordova. I have no problem pulling contacts, but no luck with the actual device's phone number. Found some work around using Java, but that seems absurd to go jump through so many hoops for something similar as this.

This [plugin](https://github.com/oneminutedistraction/phonenumber) apparently works on certain phones. Both phones I tested it on, returns blank.

Comment: not possible in iOS.

Comment: Wouldn't want random apps accessing my number either. Makes sense that it isn't exposed for obvious security reasons

Answer (score 0):

as @webduvet said, not possible on IOS, however the plugin is only for Android and as per the source code he is doing right. But one should also give `permission` to access device details in Android.

Permission for reading such things in Android Device is `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>` which is not available in plugin.