# Javascript: How is it possible to get a mobile phone number of a user?

Tags: javascript, mobile, exploit

I was on facebook and clicked a "click bait" website about top 10 most expensive dogs. a riveting read as you all will agree. after leaving the website, I got a text message saying i have subscribed to best dog facts.

How is this even possible? Assume i clicked something on the website that gave consent, is there an actual javascript api that can get a number/or send a text message to a mobile device?

More information:
the website was loaded in facebook apps built in browser  (some exploit there?)
my phone is a samsung galaxy s7, not rooted

any ideas would be great as every search so far has yielded no results pointing towards this actually being possible. yet i just experienced it.

Comment: Did you check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038955/reliable-way-to-get-device-phone-number

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are a victim of mechanizm called WAP billing [thread on security stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/99818/dangers-of-wap-billing), [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAP_billing)